# Use Windows ffmpeg to record audio output without using the StereoMix

Tags: windows, macos, audio, ffmpeg, output

I am looking for a way to record the audio output (speakers) using Windows ffmpeg.
I need to do this WITHOUT installing any extra dshow filters and without having the StereoMix input enabled (since this is not available on many computers).

I have read in the ffmpeg documentation that the -map would allow redirecting an audio output so that ffmpeg sees it as an audio input but I can't find any example of how to do that.

In Linux I managed to do it like this:

```
ffmpeg -f pulse -ac 2 -ar 44100 -i alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1f.4.analog-stereo.monitor -f pulse -ac 2 -ar 44100 -i alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1f.4.analog-stereo -filter_complex amix=inputs=2 test.mp4
```

However I can't find a similar way to do it in Windows and MacOSX.

So in short, is it possible with the Windows ffmpeg to record audio from the speakers without extra dshow filters (out-of-the-box)? Same question goes for MacOSX.

Thanks!

Comment: there is no native input device for that presently, so either write one and submit it or install a dshow filter (virtual-audio-capturer).  With OS X I believe you'd have to install something as well (soundflower?)

Comment: rogerdpack, thanks for the input, I already found out about soundflower on mac, I just didn't know about virtual-audio-capturer. So many thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\DIR>choco install ffmpeg

C:\DIR>ffmpeg -list_devices true -f dshow -i dummy
[...]
[dshow @ 00000000005d1140] DirectShow audio devices
[dshow @ 00000000005d1140]  "Microphone Array (Realtek High "
[dshow @ 00000000005d1140]     Alternative name "@device_cm_{33D9A762-90C8-11D0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}\Microphone Array (Realtek High "
[...]

C:\DIR>ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="Microphone Array (Realtek High " NAME.wav
[...]
[press 'q' to quit]
[...]
```

To play the file, I figured I needed to apply a work-around to a bug in the Windows SDL output device configuration,

> https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6891

```
C:\DIR>@rem https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/6891
C:\DIR>@rem set SDL_AUDIODRIVER=directsound or winmm
C:\DIR>set SDL_AUDIODRIVER=winmm
C:\DIR>ffplay -i NAME.wav
```

It's fun to watch ffplay's real-time spectrogram.

```
C:\DIR>ffplay -f dshow -i audio="Microphone Array (Realtek High "
[...]
[press 'm' to mute the echo]
[...]
[press 'q' to quit]
[...]
```

I saw other ways of playing the audio file using the Windows API from Python or its media player.

```
C:\DIR>type winsound-play.py
import sys, winsound

winsound.PlaySound(sys.argv[1], winsound.SND_FILENAME)

C:\DIR>c:\Python27\python winsound-play.py NAME.wav

C:\DIR>explorer NAME.wav

C:\DIR>"%ProgramFiles%\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe" /task NowPlaying %CD%\NAME.wav
```